# Core-Dump under Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-studio-2012, dump

Is there a possibility to have some kind of core-dump-like debug file in case of a crash when using windows and visualStudio 2012? If yes: how can this be created/how can creation be invoked in case my application crashes?

Comment: Is [Dr Watson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Watson_(debugger)) still a thing?

Comment: Look into [`procdump.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump). You can have it "listen" to "conditions" of your process and automatically create a dump if one or more are met.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can get [minidump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Debug/minidump-files)s. You can also get full dumps. See, for example, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/254649/overview-of-memory-dump-file-options-for-windows

Comment: Thanks but this requires an active call to MiniDumpWriteDump(), right? Means when I have no idea where my application crashes or when it dies without falling into any exception handler, this does not work as the dump has to be created by the failing application itself, not by any other higher-level instance (as it would happen on Linux)

Comment: You can setup your Windows so it does that automatically on every crash. See [Collecting User-Mode Dumps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps).

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a standard file format for process dump files. They are called [Minidump Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/minidump-files). A minidump file can be as small or as large as you want. The file format is understood by all Windows debuggers (although Visual Studio struggles with some).

Minidump files can be created either manually with a call to [`MiniDumpWriteDump`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minidumpapiset/nf-minidumpapiset-minidumpwritedump) or automatically by Windows Error Reporting (WER) (see [Collecting User-Mode Dumps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps) for instructions). Setup of the latter is commonly done by the application installer.

If you decide to create minidump files from your application, you need to set up an unhandled exception filter ([`SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-setunhandledexceptionfilter)). The exception filter should not call `MiniDumpWriteDump` directly<sup>1</sup>, but rather launch an external process that does. The required information can be passed on the command line.

To learn how to work with minidump files, you can also have Task Manager create one for you. On the *Details* tab, you can right-click any process and select "Create dump file".

---

<sup>1</sup> *I covered the consequences of ignoring this advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62633183/1889329).*