# How to generate a dump file in Windows when my application crashes due to memory corruption or null pointer violation or another scenario?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have an MFC application which is written in VC++. While we are running that application, it might crash due to some scenario (NULL pointer access, memory violation, heap corruption, etc).

We are trying to find the issue by writing debug info to a file, but that does not work while the application is crashed, so we need a dump file to identify the issue (sometimes we are using Event Viewer, but it always shows a Windows DLL, like NTDLL or something).

So, is there any way to create a dump file automatically when my application crashes?

Comment: You can catch most errors by using `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`. Then you can create a dump using `MiniDumpWriteDump` (you need to ship `dbghelp.dll` with your app and load it with `LoadLibrary` + `GetProcAddress`). Remember that your application is crashing so you need to write low-level code: open file (`CreateFileW` is safe), write dump, close file. Do not use iostreams, etc. Also note that sometimes it's better to launch some helper app that would dump your app because it can be in a very fubar state.

Comment: Have WER do it for you: [Collecting User-Mode Dumps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps).

Comment: @Osyotr That's missing the most important detail: `MiniDumpWriteDump()` MUST be called from an external process. Don't let the documentation confuse you. It reads like that is a recommendation alone. It isn't.

Comment: @IInspectable though I agree that it's better to have an external process that does dumping, I'm sure that some minidumps can be created in-process. Also note that WER requires admin rights on user machine and can't send minidumps to your server.

Comment: @Osyotr *"I'm sure that some minidumps can be created in-process."* - [They cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62633183/1889329), no exceptions. WER is commonly set up by an installer, so you hold the permissions already. If you need to send dumps to a server you can do that from a dedicated process as well.